# Selenium en Python - Implicitly wait y explicitly wait

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Me ocurre esto con esta función, si uso un time.sllep() funciona correctamnte pero por lo que tengo entendido es bastante ineficiente usarlo.

```
def visible_en_tienda(driver): 
 time.sleep(2)

 xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/section/div[5]/div/div/label/span"  
 visible = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath) 
 visible.click() 

 xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/section/div[13]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/label/span"
 visible = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath) 
 visible.click()
```

Luego intenté usar el implicitly_wait() pero es como si no existiera

```
def visible_en_tienda(driver):

 driver.implicitly_wait(10)
 xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/section/div[5]/div/div/label/span" 
 visible = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath) 
 visible.click() 

 driver.implicitly_wait(10) 
 xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/section/div[13]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/label/span"
 visible = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
 visible.click()
```

Y me da este error, por lo visto hay otro elemento encima durante la carga...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: 
Message: Element <span class="control__indicator"> is not clickable 
at point (374,322.5) because another element <div class="bg"> 
obscures it
```

Entonces intento usar el wait explicito de esta forma pero sigue dandome el mismo error.

```
def visible_en_tienda(driver):
 wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)     

 xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/section/div[5]/div/div/label/span" 
 visible = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath))) 
 visible.click() 

 xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/section/div[13]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/label/span"
 visible = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath)))
 visible.click()
```

Entonces no tengo muy claro si es que los waits no funcionan o es que los estoy usando mal. Y si los estoy usando mal ¿Qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que yo utilizo para evitar las esperas explicitas, es esto (aunque es codigo Java, en Python será practicamente igual):

```
new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(IMPLICIT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(RETRY_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
            .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(xpath)));
```

Donde:

1. `IMPLICIT_TIMEOUT` es el valor maximo, en segundos, que va a esperar el driver por el elemento
2. `RETRY_TIME` cada cuanto tiempo busco de nuevo el elemento.
3. `xpath` el Xpath del objeto a buscar.

Esto devuelve un WebElement con el que podras interactuar, ya sea para hacer un click o para enviar texto.

Comment: Hola!! Gracias por contestar y por la explicación, pero verás, en Python no funciona IMPLICIT_TIMEOUT... simplente sigue de largo y no espera... debe ser un bug o algo así... un error de los desarrolladores porque si no no me lo explico. Tu explicación me ha servido para darme cuenta de que lo estaba haciendo bien y además para conocer la existencia del parametro RETRY_TIME que en la documentacion ni lo nombran, así que te voy a dar un voto positivo!! Gracias y Saludos!!